# Group 'n' rows in to columns - oracle

Tags: oracle, split, rows

I have a situation where I need to split 'n' rows  in to column group. For example, Below is dataset

```
COMMENT_TEXT  
  T1
  T2
  T3
  T4
  T5
  T6
```

Expected Output:

```
  SUN  MON  TUE
  T1   T2   T3
  T4   T5   T6
```

My Query:

```
SELECT htbp1.comment_text 
FROM hxc_time_building_blocks htbp,
     hxc_time_building_blocks htbp1 
  WHERE     htbp1.parent_building_block_id = htbp.time_building_block_id
     AND htbp1.parent_building_block_ovn = htbp.parent_building_block_ovn
     AND htbp.parent_building_block_id = 116166
     AND htbp.parent_building_block_ovn = 1      
ORDER BY htbp1.time_building_block_id
```

Is there any way I can do PIVOT with a 'n' rows and without aggregate function?

Edit: T1/T2/T3 as sample data sets but in real it can be any random free text or null.

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT htbp1.comment_text, TO_CHAR (htbp.start_time, 'DY') par_time,
trunc((rownum-1) / 7) buck
FROM hxc_time_building_blocks htbp,
 hxc_time_building_blocks htbp1,
 hxc_timecard_summary hts 
 WHERE     hts.RESOURCE_ID = :p_resource_id
                 AND TRUNC(hts.STOP_TIME) = TRUNC(:p_wkend_date)
  AND htbp1.parent_building_block_id = htbp.time_building_block_id
 AND htbp1.parent_building_block_ovn = htbp.parent_building_block_ovn
 AND htbp.parent_building_block_id = hts.timecard_id
 AND htbp.parent_building_block_ovn = hts.timecard_ovn      
ORDER BY htbp1.time_building_block_id ) PIVOT( max(comment_text)   FOR par_time
                                                   IN  ('SUN' AS "SUN",
                                                       'MON' AS "MON",
                                                       'TUE' AS "TUE",
                                                       'WED' AS "WED",
                                                       'THU' AS "THU",
                                                       'FRI' AS "FRI",
                                                       'SAT' AS "SAT"));
```

When I added the another table 'hxc_timecard_summary' which is parent then data is going crazy, but if I use the hardcoded parameters like the one in the first then the rows are showing up fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PIVOT also uses an aggregate function but you don't need a GROUP BY:

```
with tab as (
  select sysdate - 7 date_col, 'T1' comment_text from dual
  union all select sysdate - 6, 'T2' from dual
  union all select sysdate - 5, 'T3' from dual
  union all select sysdate - 4, 'T4' from dual
  union all select sysdate - 3, 'T5' from dual
  union all select sysdate - 2, 'T6' from dual
  union all select sysdate - 1, 'T7' from dual
)
select * from (select to_char(date_col, 'D') day_of_week, comment_text from tab)
PIVOT (max(comment_text) for day_of_week in (7 as sun, 1 as mon, 2 as tue));
```

Also, I suppose you need the second column with a date to form your new columns.

And you cannot use expressions for FOR clause - this should be column(s). For example, this won't work:

```
select * from tab
PIVOT (max(comment_text) for to_char(date_col, 'D') in (7 as sun, 1 as mon, 2 as tue));
```

because of `to_char(date_col, 'D')`

Comment: You are awesome. Thank you so much. The second PIVOT worked but there is one more issue I ran in to. Could you please look at the edited question?

Comment: @Phani , trunc((rownum-1) / 7) buck - you don't need this

Comment: @Phani DY - it's NLS dependent so be careful

Comment: Is there any way you could chat with me?? If I remove it then I am loosing the second row.

Comment: @Phani Instead of rownum try row_number() over (order by whatever_you_need). I suppose your pivoted columns show the data erratically

Comment: @Phani P.S. chat will be offered if there are some more posts

Comment: you have a teamviewer so that I can share my screen?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64099/discussion-between-multisync-and-phani).

Answer (score 0):

Try using [pivot](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/sql/11g-pivot-097235.html).
It allows rows to be mapped to columns.
Its from 11g onwards I believe.

Comment: Problem here is the table structure is a tree based and the comment lies under 2nd node of tree. So, Pivot is throwing up multiple rows so for example..if I have 7 days and if my parent node has two children then it's returning out 14 rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
with tab as (
  select 'T1' comment_text from dual
  union all select 'T2' from dual
  union all select 'T3' from dual
  union all select 'T4' from dual
  union all select 'T5' from dual
  union all select 'T6' from dual
)
select regexp_substr(txt, '[^,]+', 1, 1) sun, 
       regexp_substr(txt, '[^,]+', 1, 2) mon, 
       regexp_substr(txt, '[^,]+', 1, 3) tue
from (
  select buck, wm_concat(comment_text) txt
  from (
    select comment_text, trunc((rownum-1) / 3) buck 
    from (select comment_text from tab order by comment_text)
  )    
  group by buck
);
```

`wm_concat(comment_text)` (Oracle 10g) =
`listagg(comment_text, ',') within group(order by comment_text)` (Oracle 11g)

But these two functions are both aggregate

Answer (score 0):

My third try, no aggregate functions at all (works fine in Oracle 10g)

```
with tab as (
  select 'T1' comment_text from dual
  union all select 'T2' from dual
  union all select 'T3' from dual
  union all select 'T4' from dual
  union all select 'T5' from dual
  union all select 'T6' from dual
)

select regexp_substr(txt, '[^(#####)]+', 1, 1) sun, 
       regexp_substr(txt, '[^(#####)]+', 1, 2) mon, 
       regexp_substr(txt, '[^(#####)]+', 1, 3) tue
from (
  select sys_connect_by_path(comment_text, '#####') txt, parent_id
  from (
    select rownum id, comment_text, mod(rownum-1, 3) parent_id 
    from (select comment_text from tab order by comment_text)
  )
  start with parent_id = 0
  connect by prior id = parent_id    
) where parent_id = 2;
```

Comment: As I have updated my question, would it work if I have any random text not any pattern pls?

Comment: @Phani sys_connect_by_path(comment_text, ',') - you need to use here a symbol which cannot appear in your text (the same with regexp_substr)

Comment: @Phani or a sequence of symbols (I've updated my answer)